# Can I Rewrite valet requests to laravel app in a subfolder

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, codeigniter, nginx, laravel-valet

I have an old codeigniter app that I am maintaining and want to run laravel alongside, develop here and eventually migrate. The file structure is below:

```
/codeigniter
/laravel
/site
 -index.php > codeigniter front controller
 -app
  -index.php > laravel front controller
```

I can do this on production but I'm struggling to configure with valet and ultimately nginx.

When I access https://site.dev I hit codeigniter.
When I access https://site.dev/app/ I hit laravel

If I were to access https://site.dev/app/users I'm then back to codeigniter.

Is this set up possible with valet?

Thanks for any help
Joe